# To print execution time of Script from Script?

Tags: shell-script, time

I'm searching PDF files in all directories except those in `.texpadtmp` by code originally based on [this discussion](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1700370).

```
function findpdfs() {
find . -iname '*.pdf' -not -path "*.texpadtmp*" | while read filename
do
  echo -e "\033[34;1m// === PDF Document:\033[33;1m $filename\033[0m"
  pdftotext -enc Latin1 "$filename" - | grep --color=always -i $1
  time         # TODO problem here!
done
}
```

where, in the last line, I try to print the execution time of the script for each file unsuccessfully.

**How can you print the time correctly?**

My next goal is then to have all execution times and present them as percentages in the output as whole numbers so I can approximate where most of time resources are going.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Method #1 - Using begin/end time

You'll typically see it done where you do:

```
begin=$(date +%s) 
... do something ...
end=$(date +%s)
```

And then subtract the `$begin` time from the `$end` time to get the number of seconds that have elapsed.

```
tottime=$(expr $end - $begin)
```

#### Method #2 - Using the time commands

The other method would be to use the `time` command that's built into Bash or the `time program that's included with most Linux/Unix systems here,`/bin/time`.

You can check like so:

```
$ type -a time
time is a shell keyword
time is /usr/bin/time
time is /bin/time
```

You use it like so:

*built-in*

```
$ time sleep 5

real    0m5.004s
user    0m0.001s
sys 0m0.001s
```

*standalone executable*

```
$ /bin/time sleep 5
0.00user 0.00system 0:05.00elapsed 0%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 628maxresident)k
0inputs+0outputs (0major+191minor)pagefaults 0swaps
```

They provide different outputs but you can use which ever suites your needs. Both will print the elapse time that a command takes to run:

```
$ time <cmd>
```

So you could prefix your `pdf2text` command.

Comment: Yes, I remember there is some parameters in some time command about to start and to end timing. Something like tit and tot, cannot remember exact names. Yes, I think the last approach is in Matlab and its timing facilities.

Comment: There isn't anything like tit/tot in Unix. I've only seen the 2 approaches that I've shown. In programming languages such as Perl/Ruby there are libraries that'll present you with similar methods but are typically more featureful. I seem to recall doing a similar thing in Matlab, but it's been ~10+ years since I've touched Matlab.